# If a class has no state, should all the methods be static?

Tags: java, oop, static

Lets say I have a Helper class like with a few methods

```
public class SomeClassesHelperClass(){

    public List removeDuplicatesFromTheGivenList(List someList){
    // code here 
    }

    public int returnNumberOfObjectsThatHaveSomeSpecialState(List someList){
    // code here
    }
}
```

What are the advantages / disadvantages of making the methods in this class static? Which is the better practice?

Comment: `returnNumberOfObjectsThatHaveSomeSpecialState` That's really a bad name for a method.

Comment: I'm sure this is a dupe, but the answer is that methods should only be static when there's only one possible way to do a job, such as basic math functions. Otherwise, you can't use mock objects for testing, or allow pluggable implementations.

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun Objective-C folks don't agree with a good reason unless your meant the word 'return'.

Comment: If a class truly has no state, and will never be extended, it should be declared `static`, and `final`.  Be careful here though, many times I see classes marked static which later need extension. If it really is a helper class, perfect use though.

Comment: @SajalDutta Well.. I only care about Java folks :D

Comment: I think this should go to programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: +1 @DaveHowes.  Dependency injection is a powerful tool.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your class provides **only** utility methods (like yours), I believe it's better to:

- make the class `final` (there's no point to extend it)
- define а `private` constructor to avoid any attempt to create an instance of the class
- make all the methods `static`.

Comment: And define private constructor to avoid any attempt to create its instance.

Comment: If you are defining class in C#, then you can append the keyword static and you won't need to implement a private constructor.

Comment: Even though we don't have state in classes, if we had subclasses and wanted to use polymorphism, should the methods still be defined as static?

Comment: @AliDehkhodaei no subclasses, that's why I've suggested to make the class `final`. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you decide to make all the methods static then you need to be aware of the impact that that will have on your ability to test other classes that depend up on it.

It severely limits your options for mocking ( or at least makes it more painful )

I don't think there is a right answer to our question - it depends on what the methods do. For example, it's easy to envisage a stateless data access object - if you make all its methods static then you are building a dependency on the data source in to your test cycle, or making your mocking code much uglier

Comment: 1. A good mocking framework should not have problems mocking static methods 2. If it really is a utility class (think something like `Collections.sort(List)`) you probably won't need to mock it.

Comment: @assylias - agreed on both counts - but the OP asked a much broader question. I would certainly not make all the methods on my Spring injected stateless singleton service classes static, even though the object itself retains no state. It depends on how you intend to use the class.

Answer (score 1):

Make them static when they use no state from an object. Most of it are helper classes like Math. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html